# Куда отправляются логи, отправленные с помощью syslog&

Tags: linux, c

изучаю демонов в linux на примере https://gist.github.com/hvmonteiro/9992a41a1a412dbc36d76cb9f99774b0.

Проверял, как реализованы обработчики сигналов в этой программе.
И не смог найти где я могу прочитать логи отправленные командой syslog в это программе.

Как я понял здесь мы подключаем нашу программу к системным логам.

```
openlog(logPrefix,LOG_PID|LOG_CONS|LOG_NDELAY|LOG_NOWAIT,LOG_LOCAL0);

    (void)setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(logLevel));
```

А тут отправляем их.

```
syslog(LOG_LOCAL0|LOG_INFO,"caught SIGUSR1 - soft shutdown");
```

Вопрос состоит в том, где я могу их посмотреть?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Файла syslog там нет.

Comment: /var/log/syslog или /var/log/messages (вообще, описывается в /etc/syslog.conf, также можно почитать [Linux Logs Explained](https://www.plesk.com/blog/featured/linux-logs-explained/))